# Inconsistent display of number of badges on profile page on mobile website

Tags: support, bug, badges, profile-page, mobile-web

On a [user's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile#badges), the rarest badges are shown. It also shows the total number of badges you have. On Desktop, it's shown as 'Badges (*x*)':

[image]

but on Mobile, it's 'Rarest badges (*x*)' with the same number, even though the shown badges are less than *x* and most of your badges aren't rare:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem here, it displays the rarest badges out of the respective categories (gold, silver and bronze).

Comment: @Luuklag The number of rarest badges isn't 29, it's 8. (It's never higher than 9, FWIW.)

Comment: Well its confusing indeed @Glorfindel, but the intention here is to show the rarest of your badges. Of which they have 29 in total (as indicated by the count by the respective categories).

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity, I hope this is still consistent with what you mean.

Comment: Well, it can be higher than 9.  In my case, [I have 22 of my rarest badges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXsYb.png), owing to the fact that I have quite a lot of Steward badges.